# Error: dim(X) must have a positive length when using "lapply"

Tags: r

When running this command:

```
tmp <- lapply(tmp, function(y) apply(sapply(y, function(x) unique(grpproc[,2]) %in% x), 1, sum))
```

I get the error:

```
Error in apply(sapply(y, function(x) unique(grpproc[, 2]) %in% x), 1,  :     
dim(X) must have a positive length
```

I believe I possibly need a different apply statement there maybe?  Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're nesting a `sapply` within an `apply` within a `lapply` which is pretty complicated normally, but impossible to understand when you haven't provided a representable example

Comment: `lapply(apply(sapply` is pretty convoluted. Please, share a reproducible example and state the logic of what you are trying to do.

Comment: ah okay i see.  Sorry about that, the data is kind of hard to reproduce because it is extremely long.  But i will try my best to.

Comment: you could nest a few more of them: `rapply`, `tapply`, `mapply`... ;-) [j/k](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=j%2Fk).

Comment: haha, im trying to help a coworker out with their code.

Comment: working on getting that now

Comment: how can I add a piece of example data to here?

Answer (score 0):

sapply() returns a vector, but apply() is looking for a matrix

```
xx <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
dim(sapply(xx, mean)) # NULL
xxx <- matrix(rep(xx,3), nrow = 3) # what happens if we give sapply a matrix?
dim(sapply(xxx, mean)) # why?
sapply(xxx, mean) # because it returns a vector
```

Possibly your colleague may want to use sum() instead of apply()?  Or a different apply function that returns the correct matrix or data.frame.

Comment: @ChrisYee90 did this answer your question?